# adding double value field to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

If I want to add a NSString field to database I can do it by following way

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [PlaceName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

where, PlaceName is variable of type NSString inserted into column number 1. now If I want to add double field to database how can do it?

I tried following,

```
sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 4, [PlaceLongitude doubleValue]);
```

which gave error: Cannot convert to a pointer type.

Please help me. Thanks for any help, in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `PlaceLongitude`?

Comment: If it is a double, you can directly pass it to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Save double to DB**
If `PlaceLongitude` is `double`, you can directly pass it to the method,

```
sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 4, PlaceLongitude);
```

The error `Cannot convert to a pointer type` is because you are trying to call a method on a primitive type (double).

**Retrieve double from DB**

```
NSString *longStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];
Place.PlaceLongitude = [longStr doubleValue];
```

Comment: Thanks. that really helped....!! When I display the database, I can assign database value to NSString in following way                                           Place.PlaceName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)]                           where Place the object that holds PlaceName, PlaceLongitude etc. Can you please tell me similar statement for double value PlaceLongitude?

Comment: Thanks boss. This again worked perfectly.  If possible I would have 2 "green V label" to your answer.